# How can I combine a bar and a line chart without a time series in Grafana?

Tags: grafana

I'm trying to make a classic Pareto chart in Grafana: categories on the X axis, bars of totals on the left Y, cumulative percent line on the right Y. But, I can't figure out how to mix & match lines and bars in Grafana, outside of the specialized "time series" visualization which doesn't apply here.

There's an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59513362/how-to-mix-bar-and-lines-in-grafana-in-one-chart) for an older version of the app but it no longer applies. This seems like really basic functionality so it *must* exist...right?

Comment: I think Grafana is (or maybe was) seen as a tool for primarily showing time related data. At least that's how I explain to myself why it frequently is lacking in functionality of more "static" data. But what is lacking if default panels, can frequently [be found](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/isaozler-paretochart-panel/) in community developed plugins.